# Genymotion emulators giving Open GL error on Kubuntu 13.10 64-bit

Tags: android, ubuntu, opengl-es, android-emulator, genymotion

I have been using the Genymotion Android emulator for a while on Kubuntu, but recently I have run into Open GL errors that prevent it from working. Interestingly enough, I have an older Galaxy Nexus 4.2.2 emulator image that works fine (though it complains about a version mismatch when I start it), but if I try to create any of the newer images, the emulator fails to start up. When I check logcat, I see the following error:

```
I/SurfaceFlinger(  459): SurfaceFlinger's main thread ready to run. Initializing graphics H/W...
D/libEGL  (  459): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
D/        (  459): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb890b898, tid 460
D/libEGL  (  459): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
D/libEGL  (  459): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
E/setdpi  (  463): Setting DPI to 213
E/SurfaceFlinger(  459): hwcomposer module not found
W/SurfaceFlinger(  459): getting VSYNC period from fb HAL: 16666666
W/SurfaceFlinger(  459): no suitable EGLConfig found, trying without EGL_FRAMEBUFFER_TARGET_ANDROID
W/SurfaceFlinger(  459): no suitable EGLConfig found, trying without EGL_RECORDABLE_ANDROID
E/Trace   (  459): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
W/GraphicBufferAllocator(  459): WOW! gralloc alloc failed, waiting for pending frees!
W/GraphicBufferAllocator(  459): alloc(1280, 800, 1, 00001a00, ...) failed -5 (I/O error)
E/SurfaceFlinger(  459): GraphicBufferAlloc::createGraphicBuffer(w=1280, h=800) failed (I/O error), handle=0x0
E/BufferQueue(  459): [FramebufferSurface] dequeueBuffer: SurfaceComposer::createGraphicBuffer failed
E/EGL_emulation(  459): tid 460: init(267): error 0x3003 (EGL_BAD_ALLOC)
E/SurfaceTextureClient(  459): getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x0
E/EGL_emulation(  459): tid 460: eglCreateWindowSurface(631): error 0x3003 (EGL_BAD_ALLOC)
E/libEGL  (  459): eglQuerySurface:403 error 300d (EGL_BAD_SURFACE)
E/libEGL  (  459): eglQuerySurface:403 error 300d (EGL_BAD_SURFACE)
D/SurfaceFlinger(  459): setOrientation, mFbdev=0xb8913df0, mFbDev->setOrientation=0xb679be20, orientation=0
I/gralloc_vbox86(  459): setOrientation: orientation=0
E/libEGL  (  459): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
F/libc    (  459): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 460 (SurfaceFlinger)
I/DEBUG   (  100): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   (  100): Build fingerprint: 'generic/vbox86tp/vbox86tp:4.2.2/JDQ39E/eng.buildbot.20131111.233324:userdebug/test-keys'
I/DEBUG   (  100): Revision: '0'
I/DEBUG   (  100): pid: 459, tid: 460, name: SurfaceFlinger  >>> /system/bin/surfaceflinger <<<
I/DEBUG   (  100): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  100):     eax 00000000  ebx b7121ff4  ecx b8913a80  edx 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  100):     esi 00000000  edi b890b518
I/DEBUG   (  100):     xcs 00000073  xds 0000007b  xes 0000007b  xfs 00000000  xss 0000007b
I/DEBUG   (  100):     eip b7595d36  ebp b89169a8  esp b6d69bcc  flags 00010246
I/DEBUG   (  100): 
I/DEBUG   (  100): backtrace:
I/DEBUG   (  100):     #00  pc 00027d36  /system/lib/libc.so (strlen+6)
I/DEBUG   (  100):     #01  pc 00000030  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  100): 
I/DEBUG   (  100): stack:
I/DEBUG   (  100):          b6d69b8c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  100):          b6d69b90  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  100):          b6d69b94  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  100):          b6d69b98  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  100):          b6d69b9c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  100):          b6d69ba0  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  100):          b6d69ba4  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  100):          b6d69ba8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  100):          b6d69bac  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  100):          b6d69bb0  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  100):          b6d69bb4  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  100):          b6d69bb8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  100):          b6d69bbc  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  100):          b6d69bc0  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  100):          b6d69bc4  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  100):          b6d69bc8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  100):     #00  b6d69bcc  b71066db  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::String8::setTo(char const*)+43)
I/DEBUG   (  100):          b6d69bd0  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  100):          b6d69bd4  b6d69c4c  [stack:460]
I/DEBUG   (  100):          b6d69bd8  b70bb98c  /system/lib/libEGL.so
I/DEBUG   (  100):          b6d69bdc  b7047129  /system/lib/libEGL.so (android::egl_display_t::HibernationMachine::decWakeCount(android::egl_display_t::HibernationMachine::WakeRefStrength)+73)
I/DEBUG   (  100):          b6d69be0  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  100):          b6d69be4  b70b7ff4  /system/lib/libEGL.so
I/DEBUG   (  100):          b6d69be8  00003000  
I/DEBUG   (  100):          b6d69bec  b7044790  /system/lib/libEGL.so (android::egl_tls_t::getError()+64)
I/DEBUG   (  100):          b6d69bf0  b70b7ff4  /system/lib/libEGL.so
I/DEBUG   (  100):          b6d69bf4  b70b7ff4  /system/lib/libEGL.so
I/DEBUG   (  100):          b6d69bf8  b757e339  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_mutex_lock+9)
I/DEBUG   (  100):          b6d69bfc  b71b1ff4  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so
I/DEBUG   (  100):          b6d69c00  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  100):          b6d69c04  b890b518  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  100):          b6d69c08  b89169a8  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  100):          ........  ........
I/DEBUG   (  100):     #01  b89169b0  b8907030  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  100):          b89169b4  b8907030  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  100):          b89169b8  b8907030  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  100):          b89169bc  b8907030  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  100):          b89169c0  b8907030  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  100):          b89169c4  b8907030  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  100):          b89169c8  b71afd48  /system/lib/libsurfaceflinger.so
I/DEBUG   (  100):          b89169cc  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  100):          b89169d0  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  100):          b89169d4  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  100):          b89169d8  00000004  
I/DEBUG   (  100):          b89169dc  00000601  
I/DEBUG   (  100):          b89169e0  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  100):          b89169e4  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  100):          b89169e8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  100):          b89169ec  00000000  
D/Sensors (  381): Client connection accepted (43)
E/installd(  107): eof
E/installd(  107): failed to read size
I/installd(  107): closing connection
I/ServiceManager(   91): service 'display' died
I/ServiceManager(   91): service 'scheduling_policy' died
I/ServiceManager(   91): service 'batteryinfo' died
I/ServiceManager(   91): service 'usagestats' died
I/ServiceManager(   91): service 'power' died
I/ServiceManager(   91): service 'telephony.registry' died
I/ServiceManager(   91): service 'entropy' died
I/ServiceManager(   91): service 'sensorservice' died
W/AudioFlinger(  105): power manager service died !!!
D/AndroidRuntime(  468): 
D/AndroidRuntime(  468): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit <<<<<<
D/AndroidRuntime(  468): CheckJNI is OFF
```

So apparently this is an Open GL issue.

I recently upgraded Kubuntu to 13.10 (in fact, I ran into some issues on the upgrade and ended up wiping it and creating a fresh install). My graphics card is an NVIDIA GeForce 8400 GS Rev. 3, and I'm running the proprietary driver, v319.32 on X.org v1.14.3, kernel version 3.2.0-37-generic x86_64.

Has anyone else out there gotten Genymotion emulators to work with a similar configuration?

EDIT: Forgot to mention, I have 16GB of RAM.

Comment: I think this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23560545/genymotion-opengl-error

Comment: Well, 13.04 is a couple years old version of Kubuntu. I'm over Ubuntu 15.04 and all is working flawlessly.

Comment: Have you enable your Virtual Technology (VT-x) under CPU feature in side BIOS.By default it is disabled so you have to enable it by using BIOS setting.

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is quite old,
According to Genymotion's system requirements page for linux

**System Requirements**

- Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr) or above (64bit) Debian 8 (Jessie) (64 bit).
- 64 bit CPU, with VT-x or AMD-V capability, enabled in BIOS settings
- Recent and dedicated GPU
- 400 MB disk space
- 2GB RAM

Answer (score 0):

It is caused by virtualisation reasons i don't understand quite good myself. Update your OS and this will deal with the version differences in the virtualisation technology. I am using 14.04 Ubuntu. When i was with 12.04 i had the same issue and upgrade solved it

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your OS, as said earlier your version of Kubuntu is a bit old.
Or you check that you have the latest driver for your graphic card and update it if that's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command in your terminal

```
sudo  /sbin/rcvboxdrv
```