# Genymotion openGL error

Tags: android, opengl, genymotion

I am trying to install genymotion,after pressing play button it shows the following error.
[image]

I don't know how to update openGL library or how to check current version. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> I don't know how to update openGL library

First things first, *OpenGL is not a library*. It's a drawing API for talking with the graphics drivers to make the GPU do nice things.

As such, OpenGL comes as part of the graphics drivers. Unfortunately Microsoft decided that they don't like OpenGL and would not ship drivers fully equipped with modern OpenGL profiles through Windows' built in driver update mechanism. Oh, yes, they added legacy support for OpenGL-1.4 (which was specified in 2002), thank you very much.

So you have to take things into your own hands. First step: Go to the control panel and open the Hardware Manager. In the section "Graphics Cards" you'll find the name of your GPU. Most likely it will be made by one of *Intel*, *Nvidia*, *AMD* or *ATI*.

Depending on who made it you can find the drivers on

- Intel: http://downloadcenter.intel.com/default.aspx
- NVidia: http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx
- AMD and ATI: http://support.amd.com/en-us/download

Select the drivers appropriate for your system, download and install them.

> or how to check current version.

Since OpenGL is not a library the truly limiting factor is the GPU in your system. If your GPU doesn't OpenGL-2 you're SOL. However you'd have a really, really old GPU for that and Windows-8 would not even boot on a system with such a GPU that old. Update your GPU drivers and you should be fine.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem. In my case (I use windows 7) I went to Device Manager -> screen adapter and with right button I updated the software. fix it. It works.

Comment: This solved my pbm too

Answer (score 1):

If your driver is intel, it is now easy to do installation or update through out [Intel's auto update tool](http://www.intel.com/support/detect.htm), it is really easy to setup and update. however if yours is amd you could check [their detection tool](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/auto-detect-tool) which is provided by amd. nvidia is also providing their [driver's update tool](http://www.drivers.com/update-nvidia-drivers-main.php).

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same issue during my times. Please follow these :

1. Check your video card details through ControlPanel --> Device Manager --> browse over the net to update the driver related to that.
2. Alternatively you can also search in Google about the CPU you have in your system and install related drivers from the internet. For e.g., I've Intel CPU G2020 Dual core 2.9GHZ. I went to intel website and updated the drivers as per the needs from there.
3. Once your driver is updated to the latest, try to restart the system and restart the GenyMotion. That should resolve the problem.

Kindly Note that, unless your CPU and Graphic card supports Open GL, you cannot use it. FYI - all the recent chipsets are supporting Open GL by default for sure. So, Go for It!

Another option you've is letting the Windows wizard to find the drivers suitable for your cards but that may not work some times. So, do the above steps as guided.

Comment: Unless OP is using Intel integrated graphics it makes no sense going to the Intel website.

Comment: The Windows wizard is of no help, because Microsoft intentionally cripples graphics drivers and removes OpenGL support from drivers that ship with Windows or through the Windows driver update mechanism. You have to download the drivers directly from the vendor's website and install those.

Comment: @datenwolf - I've mentioned about Intel considering my CPU and system configuration and I've clearly mentioned that 'For e.g., I've' It doesn't mean every one should go to Intel website. and Why is this marked '-1'.  Any idea ?

Comment: -1 Because your answer contains misleading information. For example you mention "CPU and Graphics card support OpenGL". Wrong, the CPU has nothing to do with it. CPUs are general purpuse, it's the GPU that ultimately determines which OpenGL profile is supported (unless you fall back to software emulation, which by definition is unlimited, because all CPUs, no matter how old are general purpose and the only thing that differs is the performance). The other misinformation is suggesting the Windows driver update wizard, which helps not at all, because it only considers drivers from Microsoft.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. You are perfectly right. I should've not put that comment about CPU somehow missed my mind during the typo...Bingo !

Comment: +1 for your informative response

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52378/discussion-between-ramakishna-balla-and-datenwolf)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue. And I have no Graphic card. I just Installed one driver And it solved my issue. May be It helps some one. I just downloaded Win32_152820.exe from https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?DwnldID=23376