# Unable to launch Android Emulator and Genymotion because of video card error in Windows 8.

Tags: opengl, windows-8, android-emulator, genymotion, video-card

I'm unable to launch the android emulator as well as genymotion emulator as I get an error as below. I use a SONY VAIO, windows-8, 64 bit system. And my graphics driver is ATI Radeon HD 5000 series. 
I have the drivers up-to-date. Yet I get this error. All the solutions and blogs online give the only answer to update or reinstall the drivers. I have tried both. Please help. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your computer might have two GPU, one intel integrated and the ATI Radeon.

You can check if it is the case in the device manager in windows.
To access the device manager:

- Right-click My Computer, click Manage, and then click Device Manager.
- Deploy the "Display adapters" node.

If you have more than 2 GPU, you can either:

- update your intel GPU drivers from sony website
- force player.exe to use the ATI GPU in the Catalyst Control Center program from ATI.

You can find here the steps to force a specific GPU in the Catalyst Control Center: http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&docname=c03048374
This link is not from Sony but should also apply to your context.

If you only have one GPU in your computer, you could try to contact Genymotion support here: https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/support/

Comment: thanks, no more lags with the ATI powered gpu. @downvoter: WTF?

Answer (score -1):

Go to the control panel and open the Hardware Manager. In the section "Graphics Cards" you'll find the name of your GPU. Most likely it will be made by one of Intel, Nvidia, AMD or ATI.

Depending on who made it you can find the drivers on

http://downloadcenter.intel.com/default.aspx

http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx

http://support.amd.com/en-us/download

Select the drivers appropriate for your system, download and install them. And restart Genymotion.

Answer (score -1):

You need to update your video card driver using the latest version provided by your manufacturer (available on their website)...... it will solve the problem..
you can find the solution from here also....[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23560545/genymotion-opengl-error)