# Genymotion Virtual Device OpenGl Error

Tags: virtual, device, genymotion

I have installed Genymotion Virtual Device for Android Studio and also created virtual device in it ,but the problem is that virtual device(in Genymotion) is not getting started and showing the following error :

**Unable to start virtual device 
To start virtual device,make sure that your video card supports OpenGl 2.0 and update the drivers
Details: Failed to initialize backend EGL display (error: 4)
If possible, update your video card drivers.**

**I tried to update the video card through device manager but it says that it's up to date.**

Comment: here 
see this post 
its helpful 
[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23560545/genymotion-opengl-error/23561229

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue in windows 8.
When you try to update the graphic card driver, it says it's already up to date.

All I did to solve this is that I downloaded a Graphic card driver supported by my system i.e. dell N5050 from the dell site. I installed this driver supported by inbuilt window version 7: "Intel HD Graphics 3000 Driver_Vedio_Intel_W84_X00_A01_Setup-5PFY2_ZPE.exe  Hard-Drive."

You must install a Graphic Driver supported by your system.