# Why does Genymotion insist upon OpenGL support when Virtual Box doesn't, and how to work around?

Tags: android, opengl-es, genymotion

I am aware of [Genymotion openGL error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23560545/genymotion-opengl-error) stack overflow question.

I am attempting to run Genymotion on a Windows 10 system, but the graphics adapter is Intel G45/G43 Express Chipset WDDM1.1 and the driver supplied does not support OpenGL and Intel appear to have no interest in delivering a driver that does for Windows 10. I understand that officially this combination is **not supported**.

But here's the thing: I can start a Genymotion VM fine from Virtual Box, and it appears to work (almost) perfectly, as far as I can tell.
Certainly I don't see any problem with the graphics.
This must be using some (probably Virtual Box provided) software implementation of OpenGL.

However, when I try to start the same phone VM from the Genymotion console, or from the Genymotion button inside Android Studio, I get the error dialog-box in the linked question above.

My question is: **Why is Genymotion insisting that there is OpenGL support from the real physical display driver**? And of course, if its for a quality reason only (ie: sub-optimal user experience otherwise) **is there any way to disable this check**?

The reason this matters is that Android Studio does not list the Virtual Box started phone VM as somewhere an application can be run upon. I suspect that when Genymotion runs a phone VM, they set up something that the Android Studio integration needs, that simply running from Virtual Box doesn't provide.

In addition, I can't circumvent the Android Studio integration by deploying to a phone VM using the `gmtool device install file.apk` command bundled with Genymotion because this is a paid license feature. As you can imagine I am somewhat reluctant to purchase such a license when I know I am running in an unsupported configuration.

Purchasing new hardware also isn't an option for me in the short term.

EDIT: The justification for this question has since evaporated. Although I can't deploy using Android Studio or `gmtool.exe`, I have managed to deploy by using the phone web browser to fetch the `.apk` file. The gotcha here is that the web server must supply a `Content-Length` header or the download will fail. So I now have a workable solution.

{{{ Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm part of the Genymotion team. That's an interesting question. The answer is: yes, we ask for OpenGL drivers for performance reasons. Without this, the whole Android rendering would be handle by the CPU (as soft rendering) which is not fast enough to allow a real usage of the devices, with a seamless user experience, particularly since 4.3. If you run a 4.2.2 image from VirtualBox, you'll see the UI inside the window but the rendering will be very laggy.

As you maybe already noticed, running the Genymotion devices from VirtualBox works only for images up to 4.2.2 (released 3 years ago). The other image will show only a console window. And to be honest, you should more consider it as a side effect than a real feature. This behaviour could disappear on a future release for any reason. And there is no way to disable this check. 
As you mentioned, this configuration is really weird and exceptional. As far as I know, we don't plan to support these kind of configuration and I don't see any real viable solution to make it work properly.

Also, to explain the problem you encountered with Android Studio. When a Genymotion device start, it gets a local IP. This IP can be used to connect it to [adb](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html). Then it is possible to interact with the device like with any other Android device. This is the tools used by your IDE (and (m)any other tools communicating with Android devices.

Usually, the Genymotion app does this for you, by connecting the newly started device to adb. But you can do it yourself by running `adb connect <DEVICE_IP>:5555`. Just be careful because this connection could not be permanent and you should have to run this command regularly in some situations.

I hope this answer will help.
Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the informative feedback. I had only tried an older phone (Google Galaxy Nexus 4.1.1) which is why it appears to work for me. This is good enough for my purposes. Also, I had tried connecting with adb connect, but it didn't seem to work for me.